# How to find out sum of particular field in view codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to display the total sum of a perticular field inside forloop which is coming from the database, here is my code inside view

```
<?php foreach($exptype as $exptypes) : ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $exptypes->expensestype; ?></td>
        <?php
          $this->db->select_sum('amount');
          $this->db->from('westline_expenses');
          $this->db->where('expensestype',$exptypes->expensestype);
          $this->db->where('headofexpense','TAX');

          $query = $this->db->get();
        ?>
        <?php foreach($query as $taxexp) : ?>
        <td><?php echo $taxexp; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

but the above code doesnt work, can anyone please help me in this regard. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
foreach ($query->result() as $taxexp){
  echo $taxexp->amount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the result set from the query you ran.

```
$results = $query->result_array()
```

You can then do your foreach on the result set.

As a side note, you will need to change `echo $taxexp;` to `echo $taxexp[0];`

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

I think you are using this code in view. This code use in controller then assign in view.

```
<?php
    $this->db->select_sum('amount');
    $this->db->from('westline_expenses');
    $this->db->where('expensestype',$exptypes->expensestype);
    $this->db->where('headofexpense','TAX');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $data = $query->result_array();
    echo($data[0]['amount']); 
?>
```

Comment: According to the code... <?php foreach($exptype as $exptypes) : ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $exptypes->expensestype; ?></td>
        <?php
          $this->db->select_sum('amount');
          $this->db->from('westline_expenses');
          $this->db->where('expensestype',$exptypes->expensestype);
          $this->db->where('headofexpense','TAX');

          $query = $this->db->get();
        ?>
        <?php foreach($query as $taxexp) : ?>
        <td><?php echo $taxexp; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>